# Android: How to run a timer simultaneously while using a TextField

Tags: android, multithreading, timer, textfield

My app needs to run a timer while the user is filling the text field. I couldn't do it simultaneously. Suppose the user didn't fill the TextField in time (5 seconds) the control should go back to Home screen. Any help please ??

Comment: post code which you have done so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `TimerTask`

E.g: if you wish to start the timer as soon as the activity / user-form loads and becomes visible to the user, you can add the below code in `onStart()` method of your activity:

```
int timer_wait_time= 5000;  // in miliseconds
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask myTT= new MyTimerTask();
timer.schedule(myTT, timer_wait_time);
```

this will start the timer which will expire after the `timer_wait_time` has passed. Than it will executes the run() method of TimerTask (here "MyTimerTask").

MyTimerTask is defined like this:

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask{

            // this method gets called when the desired time is over
        public void run() {
            // put your code here about what you want to do when the timer expires.
            // maybe code to switch to other activity or disabling the text field
        }

}
```

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

use AsyncTask or make a New Thread and use its sleep method according to your needs.You can also take a look at Timer class(http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)